# Retrieve Teams channels with office connectors via powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

as the title states is there a way to retrieve the associated Office Connector url for each channels?

```
Get-TeamChannel -GroupId <GROUP_ID>
```

retrieves Channel Titles, channel Id and so on but not if an Office Connector is attached to the channel

Comment: You can use below graph api to get channel details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
However the response object will not contain details regarding connectors configured for the channels.

Comment: Hi Prasad, thanks for the reply but as you said no info about the connector url is provided. I resolved putting the url in the description.
Thanks indeed